# django+sqlite ад

Tags: django

Работаю с django 2.2.5 как сделать экспорт данных из бд в txt? начинаю писать скрипт и в строке from .models import User ошибка ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main.models'; 'main' is not a package если дописываю bot.models то что нет такого модуля, или не найдено в installed apps
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте `from models import User`.

Comment: не помогло:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\project\dejz.me\meyz\bot\db.py", line 1, in <module>
    from models import User
  File "c:\project\dejz.me\meyz\bot\models.py", line 3, in <module>
    class User(models.Model): и так далее на файлы питона ругается

Comment: Т.к. это джанга, то работать тут надо в среде джанги. Используйте `python manage.py shell` в корне проекта и затем импортируйте нужные функции, классы внутри консоли.

Comment: Мне нужно что-бы это делалось регулярно, или при добавлении нового аккаунта, просто у меня есть(сейчас пишу), бот для биржи и он данные для авторизации будет брать из txt(в котором данные из бд)

Comment: @dejz так а где по структуре проекта модель User лежит?

Comment: Попробуйте полный путь к модели: `from bot.models import User` или `from meyz.bot.models import User`. Ну и INSTALLED_APPS тоже не забудьте проверить: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#installed-apps

Answer (score 0):

Как уже было отмечено в комментариях,

> Т.к. это джанга, то работать тут надо в среде джанги. Используйте python manage.py shell в корне проекта и затем импортируйте нужные функции, классы внутри консоли.

Поскольку Вам необходимо выполнять скрипт регулярно, наиболее простой путь - [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-management-commands/), которую затем вызывать

```
python manage.py myawesomecommand
```

Вручную когда нужно или [по крону](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Из других доступных решений: [celery periodic tasks](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) (требует настройки celery), гугление также подсказало [django-background-tasks](https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (сам не пробовал, и, судя по всему, работает [не очень](https://github.com/arteria/django-background-tasks/issues)).